# PyQt : give a color to all the textof an application

Tags: pyqt, stylesheet

I would like to change the look of my application in PyQt. I want all the text (in the buttons, labels and such) to be white for exampel, and all the buttons to be a certain color.
Can I change that all at once in the mainWindow ?

I did the following to change the background color of the whole app:

```
self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow {background-color: #252526; color: #FFFFFF}")
```

If I set another stylesheet for the QPushButton for example in the same manner, the style for the QMainWindow will be overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the setStyleSheet() method on your QApplication instance and specify all object names in the CSS string:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
app.setStyleSheet('QLabel{color: #fff;} QPushButton{background-color: #000; color: #fff}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for a solution today I used the code below. Only drawback is when you disable a widget you will need to manually change the colour.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout,  QFrame

STYLE_SHEET = """

    QWidget
    {
        color: red;
    }

"""

class Win(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        container = QFrame()
        container.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        lbl = QLabel("Click this button:")
        layout.addWidget(lbl)

        btn = QPushButton("Hello World")
        layout.addWidget(btn)

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication([])
    app.setStyleSheet(STYLE_SHEET)
    win = Win()
    app.exec()
```